# How to format the layout of a CSV or JSON file

Tags: mysql, json, csv, formatting, data-representation

I need to format the layout of a CSV or JSON-file.

So I'm working on a project, where the user is able to do messurements. The results are written into a mysql database. There is a button so you can convert the database into csv-format and download it.

The table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lz8c.png)

You can see three columns named (register, pressure and timestamp).
What I want to do is to format the layout so if the user downloads the data he gets another representation of the table. The value of the timestamp shouldnt be multiple times in the table.

It's hard to explain so I created a table of how I want it to look like right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Cas.png)

Comment: so you want the timestamps to be rows and the measurements to be the data in the cells right ?

Comment: @EliteGamerSiddhu Exactly! I dont want the registers and timestamps to be multiple times in the table. So the "only actual" data should be the messurement.

Comment: This is "pivot table". MySQL does not implement this. You need in stored procedure which uses dynamic SQL.

Comment: ok, so just to be sure, if you are storing it in a json file the main dictionary should have the timestamp as the keys, the register number as the keys in the nested dict and the values of the register to be the data ?

Comment: @EliteGamerSiddhu Yes, you got it

Comment: @Akina Seems like it is! Never heared about privot tables but good to know. I think it should be possible to format it from a csv or json file. It has nothing to do with mysql right then.

Comment: I don't think you can directly do that, but i can help you with a python code to do that

Comment: @EliteGamerSiddhu This would be awesome! I've never worked with python but would love to learn it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add real data, not only images.

Here an example, similar to your input structure:

| Register | Druck | Zeitstempel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | a |
| 2 | 5 | a |
| 3 | 45 | a |
| 1 | 9 | b |
| 2 | 12 | b |

The raw data

```
Register,Druck,Zeitstempel
1,3,a
2,5,a
3,45,a
1,9,b
2,12,b
```

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and running

```
mlr --csv reshape -s Zeitstempel,Druck then unsparsify input.csv
```

You will have in output

| Register | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 | 12 |
| 3 | 45 |  |

Comment: Thats what I wanted, on point. Thank you!